Grant BigQuery metadata viewer access to user on dataset but limited to only tables the user has data viewer permission
While using the BigQuery Studio, I want to allow users to only be able to search for tables they have data viewer permission.
Example:
Dataset: test_dataset
Tables:

test_table1
test_table2
test_table3

User A only has BigQuery Data Viewer permission for test_table1, thus the intended visual at BigQuery Studio is
Dataset: test_dataset
Tables:

test_table1

Granting Data Viewer or Metadata Viewer at Dataset level shows all tables (not intended) and granting at table level doesn't list the dataset nor table in the Explorer pane, is this possible to be done?
I've tried granting Metadata Viewer and Data Viewer permission to user at table level and it doesn't work as intended.

Currently, Granting Data viewer or Metadata viewer permissions at Dataset level will let you view all the tables available in that particular Dataset and Granting table level doesn't list the Dataset as per the IAM roles documentation.
if you have a support plan, you can raise a Feature request as per your requirement as a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can raise a Feature request on the issue tracker describing your requirement.
